# iOS handoff from phone to macbook safari/chrome

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, handoff

I want to send a URL from my app to open on a laptop web browser using handoff. I have added the activity type to my app's `NSUserActivityTypes`. here is my code so far:

```
- (void)startHandoff {
    NSUserActivity *activity = [[NSUserActivity alloc] initWithActivityType:@"com.me.browse"];
    activity.webpageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:_wakeUrl];
    [activity becomeCurrent];
}
```

It doesn't seem to be appearing on my dock - does it need a special `Activity Type` if you want to use safari?

Comment: Does it work with Mobile Safari? If you open Safari in your phone, does your Mac allow you to resume from your Desktop ? I'm asking so we can see if phone to desktop handoff works correctly on your devices

Comment: yep it works fine with chrome

Comment: Doublecheck that the specified activity in the `NSUserActivityTypes` matches the one you specify in your `init` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok after tests, it seems that you need to declare the `NSUserActivity` as a instance Variable :

**So this does not work:**

```
@interface TestViewController () {
}

@end

@implementation TestViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //init hand off
    NSUserActivity *activity = [[NSUserActivity alloc] initWithActivityType:@"com.app.browse"];
    activity.webpageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.stackoverflow.com"];
    [activity becomeCurrent];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

***But this works fine:***

```
@interface TestViewController () {
      NSUserActivity *activity;
}

@end

@implementation TestViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //init hand off
   activity = [[NSUserActivity alloc] initWithActivityType:@"com.app.browse"];
    activity.webpageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.stackoverflow.com"];
    [activity becomeCurrent];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Not sure why though, I'm looking into it now

Comment: this is correct, although I had other handoff features in my app / watch app that were not working - I just restarted the devices and that seemed to fix the issues

Comment: you can also declare the activity as a property

Comment: Yes, because by default, a readwrite property will be backed by an instance variable, which will again be synthesized automatically by the compiler.

Comment: I think your NSUserActivity object gets deallocated right after viewDidLoad has finished. That's why your first approach does not work.